# angularjs, tooltipster - mouseenter issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, tooltipster

I'm using angularjs with tooltipster (http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/); I want to make a page where if you hover on text, an image is displayed (googleapis.com http request).
However, there are a couple of issues:

- When I hover over an text for the first time, only like 1/4 of image gets displayed; on the second time, the complete image is visible.
- If I hover REALLY fast, images get "burnt" to screen; as it appears, I call "hide" before the element is created (i.e. web service sends the response to my code).

I've provided an example, which can be found here: http://jsbin.com/dubome/1/edit

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: OK I've solved the first issue (1/4 of images), the solution is here: http://jsbin.com/pakelu/1/edit?html,js,output
Still having problems when I hover too fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  `element.tooltipster('hide');` gets called before `element.tooltipster('show');`
One possible solution is to check if showed the tooltipster.

Check my solution at http://jsbin.com/dofakotema/3/edit